# LocationListener leaking in fragment even when appropriately handled

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, location

I have a fragment that uses location manager (android.location.LocationManager).
mLocationManager and mLocationListener (android.location.LocationListener) are private variables to fragment.

in onResume()

```
mLocationListener = new ABCLocationListener();
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000L, 0F, mLocationListener);
```

in onPause()

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
mLocationListener = null;
```

I am getting leaks for ABCLocationListener.

logcat D/LeakCanary: |   mListener = com.xyz.android.presentation.MyFragment$ABCLocationListener@863187568 (0x33733270)

What I have checked?
1) The hash value for ABCLocationListener object being created is different than 0x33733270.
2) Both onResume and onPause method being called only once. The listener's hash value in both these methods before calling removeUpdates and requestLocationUpdates is same

Comment: Which type of parent of this fragment - Does it ViewPager or Tabs?
Also avoid creating new object from onResume() everytime. Just create once and register and deregister.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this example](https://gist.github.com/louisbl/770c0a2c636865a9025b), but I'd say either the fragment's `onResume` is being called again, or the `mLocationListener` you instantiate in `onResume` is different than the instance you unregister in `onPause`. It could help if you provide the full fragment's source code. To make sure the location listener instance is the same, make the fragment itself the listener (by implementing `LocationListener`) and register/unregister the fragment (using `this`).

Comment: I have logs. I print every time onResume is called. I see both onResume and onPause being called once. Also am toStringing the listener in both the methods before calling removeUpdates and requestLocationUpdates

Comment: You have already identified the problem yourself. The listener you're unregistering is different than the listener you're registering. To tell you why I'd have to see the code, but to solve it just make the fragment itself be the listener as I mentioned already.

Comment: I meant I have "toString()"ed the listener in both onPause and onResume. The listener is same in both the methods. Also I am logging whereever listener is created. I see listener being created only once